# Why TLSv1_2 connection is successful with older OpenSSL version in Python httplib

Tags: python, ssl, openssl, httplib, tls1.2

I am using Windows 7 OS. OpenSSL is installed in the system.

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin>openssl version
OpenSSL 0.9.8e 23 Feb 2007
```

I have a server which supports only TLSv1_2. As per documentation of OpenSSL, TLSv1_2 is supported in OpenSSL >=1.0.1. So as my installed OpenSSL is of version 0.9.8, I am expecting a failure during HTTPS connection/transaction.

https://docs.python.org/3/library/ssl.html

But still, I am able to communicate with the server using HTTPS rest APIs using TLSv1_2. Why?
My implementation is,

```
httpObj = httplib.HTTPSConnection('server_name')
httpObj.sock = socket.create_connection(('server_name', '10443'))

httpObj.sock = ssl.wrap_socket(httpObj.sock, keyfile='.\\key.pem', certfile='.\\client_cert.pem', ca_certs='.\\ca_cert.pem', ciphers='ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384', cert_reqs=ssl.CERT_REQUIRED, ssl_version=ssl.PROTOCOL_TLSv1_2)

headers = {'Accept': 'application/json', 'Accept-Language': 'en-us, en', 'Accept-Charset': 'ISO-8859-1, utf-8'}

httpObj.request('GET', URI, '', headers)
print httpObj.getresponse()
```

(There is no implementation issue in server, because I tried to connect from my linux machine with TLSv1_1 protocol and it did not work. With TLSv1_2, it worked which is expected behavior for OpenSSL version 1.0.1. In linux machine I have openssl version 1.0.1e)

Comment: The version of the openssl command line tool is not necessarily related to the version of the library used within Python. Check `ssl.OPENSSL_VERSION` instead.

Comment: But this document says, [link](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ssl.html)

`**Note:** Some behavior may be platform dependent, since calls are made to the operating system socket APIs. The installed version of OpenSSL may also cause variations in behavior. For example, TLSv1.1 and TLSv1.2 come with openssl version 1.0.1`

Comment: You can have a openssl command line binary from 0.9.8 on your system and can also have a python version linked against openssl library 1.0.1. You could even have multiple command line binaries with different versions installed in parallel. That's why you need to look at what is used by python and not what your command line says.

Comment: Understood. Thanks allot @Steffen Ullrich. May I know where is the link of python which points to openssl library in windows platform?

Comment: As I already said, check `ssl.OPENSSL_VERSION` from within python (after `import ssl`).

Comment: I already did this @SteffenUllrich. I have 2 python interpreters in my system. Python 2.7.3 uses openssl 0.9.0 and Python 2.7.10 uses openssl 1.0.1e version. I wanted to know, how python and openssl are linked? Is there any config file or ini file is available? Openssl is dynamically loaded, if yes, which dll? I just wanted to know the linking part

Comment: They are linked like any other kind of program is linked (shared or static libraries). There is no configuration - the library or the name/version are part of the binary which uses the library.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich, I want to change like this - python 2.7.10 should use openssl 0.9.8 and python 2.7.3 should use openssl 1.0.1. How can I achieve this?

Comment: You would need to compile python for yourself and give it the path to the libraries and matching include files it should use. You cannot somehow reconfigure the existing python to use a very different version of OpenSSL because they don't expose 100% the same API.